Tailwind/CSS: Why my div is not fitting the width of the image but expanding to longer width?
My div (highlighted with background yellow) is expanding horizontally i.e., it's width is increasing. I think it is increasing to the full width of the image i.e., 800px + padding. How can I make sure this div's width and height is equal to the shrunk containing image? So that the next element with text- "Test" is displayed right next to it. Thanks!


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.3"></script>

<div class="flex max-h-96">
  <div class="flex w-fit bg-yellow-100 p-2">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/800x1000" alt="MAIN_IMAGE" />
  </div>
  <div>Test</div>
</div>




Why not put the text next to the image? <img src="..."> Test 

@cloned unfortunately that image is part of another angular component with some image selectors, and I need to make a separate component, that will contain a lot of product details, buttons etc. which will be displayed right next to the image. if possible, i wanted to prefer one component for image-selector and one separate to show details, buttons etc. logic.
